# Filter out numbers Java

Tags: java, filter

I´m lost, so

```
public class Filter {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// read in two command-line arguments
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    // repeat as long as there's more input to read in
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {

        // read in the next integer
        int t = StdIn.readInt();


        if (????) {
            StdOut.print(t + " ");
        }
    }
    StdOut.println(); 
} }
```

This program is supposed to read in two integers and use them to filter out the StdIn. stream, for example if the arguments are 2,3 and StdIn 5 7 8 9 10 4 6, then it should print out 8 9 10, (skip the first 2 and print the next 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not add a counter to know which number you are at?

```
int i = 0;    
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    i++;
    // read in the next integer
    int t = StdIn.readInt();


    if ( i > a && i <= a + b) {
        StdOut.print(t + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Filter {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// read in two command-line arguments
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    // repeat as long as there's more input to read in
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {


        // read in the next integer
        int t = StdIn.readInt();

        if(a-- > 0)
            continue;

        if (b-- > 0) {
            StdOut.print(t + " ");
        }
    }
    StdOut.println(); 
} }
```

Answer (score -1):

`?????` needs to be `--a <= 0 && --b >= 0`.

Note that I'm exploiting the fact that `&&` is short-circuited. i.e. `--b` will not be evaluated until `--a` is 0 or less.

Eventually, of course, the `int` will underflow for a very long input steam session, but this is still a very cool solution.

Comment: Writing code as short and hard to read as possible isn't "cool" in my opinion

Comment: Perhaps I'm just a whole lot more brainy than you! Seriously, you could use a comment to back up this solution, if the professor wants that.

Comment: Trust me I get how it works, but that doesn't mean everyone will. Better to write something the person asking the question is guaranteed to understand than something you think is "cool".

Comment: I can't help appreciating the aesthetics of being able to replace the question marks with something that is the actual solution, and not touch any other bits of the code. There is beauty in that man. Why do we have to program to the lowest common denominator of intellectual curiosity?

Comment: @SnoopDog maybe if somebody is getting started, try keeping the solution simple so they can actually learn something new and simple they can use later instead of trying to spend a long time trying to figure it out.

Comment: I have to agree with you snoop, that is very cool. But clearly the asker is not at that level.

Comment: I don't see any harm in providing an "ace" solution - something that the OP can admire - there are several good answers here. Let's not patronise the OP.

Comment: Thank you guys, i think my brain just farted on this, sorry about the code comments. Was trying to explain the code better or something

Comment: @ÍvarKristinn: but do try to understand what is going on here. Use your line by line debugger to help and inspect the values of `a` and `b` on each iteration.

Comment: @SnoopDog okei, is java visualizer something that i can use ?

Comment: A solution that has the potential to underflow is not a good solution. There are other, more verbose ways to do this that avoid underflow errors.

Comment: @MatthewDiana it noes not have the potential to underflow. It would have to be that b > 2^31 + a but b's max value is 2^31-1 so unless the user makes a big mistake with the args (causing other problems anyway) there is no problem. Take off that down vote!